# How to pass multiple string variables to a Laravel Gate

Tags: laravel

I have a “security” service which I want to gradually move over to a Laravel Gate, so I can benefit from the helper methods that Laravel provides within the rest of the APP.

I defined the gate as follows now:

```
Gate::define('denja', function($user, $module, $permission) {
    // validation of access to $module and $permission goes here
});
```

This works fine when I do

````
$user->can('denja', ['accounting', 'invoice.create']);```
````

for instance, but I don’t see how in my routes, I can define the middleware to properly function...

````
Route::post( '/accounting/invoices', 'InvoiceController@create')
  ->middleware("can:denja,accounting,invoice.create");```
````

Passing these parameters seems to be impossible from the middleware - the page now always returns a `403`...
Any thoughts on how I can pass these parameters correctly to the gate from the Middleware?  I think it's in fact a problem with the parameters; even with a `dd()` in the defined gate, I'm getting the `403`.

I know I’m a bit “abusing” the system, but since we have an existing service that basically expects a user, module and permission under that module, I just want to delegate to that service for now...

Answer (score 2):

When you are using `can` middleware :

> The first is the name of the action we wish to authorise and the later is the route parameter we wish to pass to the policy method or a Model class path. [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#via-middleware)

For example :

```
Route::put('/post/{postId}', function (Post $post) {
    // The current user may update the post...
})->middleware('can:update,postId');
```

OR

```
Route::post('/post', function () {
    // The current user may create posts...
})->middleware('can:create,App\Post');
```

In your case :

```
Route::post( '/accounting/invoices', 'InvoiceController@create')
  ->middleware("can:denja,accounting,invoice.create");
```

which is missing the basic parameter signatures as there is no route param with name `accounting` or `invoice.create` nor a class.

**Solution :**

Remove middleware from route declaration :

```
Route::post( '/accounting/invoices', 'InvoiceController@create');
```

You can use `can()` method in your controller :

```
public function create(Request $request){

    // Initialize $model and $permissions 
    // as per your business logic
    if(!$request->user()->can('denja', $module, $permission){
        abort(403);
    }
    // continue your logic for authorised user
}
```

Even if above solution works, if you have more authorisation rules, its better to make a [policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#creating-policies) class.

Comment: Hmm - thanks for your response.  I’m actually looking for the easiest way that I can have a ‘wildcard’ gate defined which transparently checks permission with the SecurityService.  I prefer to have it in mu routes instead of in each individual controller... I now have my own middleware, but would be interested in moving it towards the Laravel gate system instead.  It seems that gates don’t allow me to do it...

Answer (score 1):

I to had this same problem so I did some digging into the 'can' middleware (Which maps to `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize`)

Once in the class we see the following code

```
 /**
     * Get the model to authorize.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string  $model
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|string
     */
    protected function getModel($request, $model)
    {
        if ($this->isClassName($model)) {
            return trim($model);
        } else {
            return $request->route($model, null) ?:
                ((preg_match("/^['\"](.*)['\"]$/", trim($model), $matches)) ? $matches[1] : null);
        }
    }
```

What this means is...

If our string passed in is a class name then return that class name

If it is not a class name then...

1) Try to get it from the route, then return the route param
2) Try to get the model from the string via the regex `"/^['\"](.*)['\"]$/"`

So now lets say we have the middleware call of 
`$this->middleware(sprintf("can:create,%s,%s", User::class, Role::SUPPORT));`

This will not work because the `Role::SUPPORT` does not match the regex

To match it we simply need to place the `Role::SUPPORT` into quotes.

TAKE NOTE OF THE "'" around the second %s
`$this->middleware(sprintf("can:create,%s,'%s'", User::class, Role::SUPPORT));`

To answer your question specifically, quote your string

```
Route::post('/accounting/invoices', 'InvoiceController@create')
  ->middleware("can:'denja','accounting','invoice.create'");
```