# Laravel - How to pass additional parameters to Gate keeping their original types?

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, laravel-8

I'm trying to pass an additional argument to `Gate` from some controller.

An error and a part of stack trace I got are as follows:

```sh
testing.ERROR: App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::App\Providers\{closure}(): Argument #2 ($request) must be of type Illuminate\Http\Request, string given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php on line 477 {"exception":"[object] (TypeError(code: 0): App\\Providers\\AuthServiceProvider::App\\Providers\\{closure}(): Argument #2 ($request) must be of type Illuminate\\Http\\Request, string given, called in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php on line 477 at /var/www/html/app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php:74)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php(477): App\\Providers\\AuthServiceProvider->App\\Providers\\{closure}(NULL, 'Illuminate\\\\Http...')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php(372): Illuminate\\Auth\\Access\\Gate->callAuthCallback(NULL, 'foo', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php(337): Illuminate\\Auth\\Access\\Gate->raw('foo', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Access/Gate.php(324): Illuminate\\Auth\\Access\\Gate->inspect('foo', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authorize.php(43): Illuminate\\Auth\\Access\\Gate->authorize('foo', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authorize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure), 'foo', 'Illuminate\\\\Http...')
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(127): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(103): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handleRequest(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure), Array)
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(55): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure), 'api', Object(Closure))
```

The problem is that `$request` (shown below) comes to `Gate` as string, not `Request` type. Using `dd` function inside `Gate` (and temporarily removing the type hint), I found the value of `$request` was merely a useless text: `"Illuminate\Http\Request"`.

How can I pass `$request` to `Gate` keeping `Request` type?

##### SomeController.php

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function fooEvents(Request $request): Response
    {
        /* some processes */
    }
}
```

##### AuthServiceProvider.php

```php
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    /**
     * @param \App\Models\User $user
     * @param Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return bool
     */
    Gate::define('foo', function (?User $user, Request $request) {

        /**
         * The problem is that the argument $request comes here as string type,
         * while I want it as Illuminate\Http\Request type;
         */

        /* some processes */
    });
}
```

##### api.php

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\SomeController;

Route::post('/foo-events', [SomeController::class, 'fooEvents'])
    ->middleware('can:foo,Illuminate\Http\Request')
    ->name('foo-events');
```

## Note:

If I directly use `Gate` inside the controller (shown below), it works fine. However I have to use `Gate` via api.php due to our team's rule. Do you have any idea?

##### SomeController.php (A working example)

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function fooEvents(Request $request): Response
    {
        if (!Gate::allows('foo', $request)) {
            return abort(404);
        }

        /* some processes */
    }
}
```

##### AuthServiceProvider.php (A working example)

(The same as the previous one)

##### api.php (A working example)

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\SomeController;

Route::post('/foo-events', [SomeController::class, 'fooEvents'])
    ->name('foo-events');
```

Comment: Have you checked what `dd($request->getContents())` returns?

Comment: If it would have been just a string you should get an error that's not of type `Illuminate\Http\Request`

Comment: I removed the type hint regarding to `$request` when I used `dd` function to check the value of the argument inside the Gate, otherwise of course I got the type error as you pointed it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests on the `can` middleware that resolves to `Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize`.

It seems it can return a class_name if a className is provided (route model binding), or a route parameter (eg: `my_route/{my_param}`, you can define your Gate with `can:foo,my_param`).

As you stated, you could pass the request as a parameter if your gate was called from your controller. But from the route definition using the "can" middleware, I wasn't able to get the entire request object as parameter.

Still, you can use the helper `request()` in your gate method to access the entire request.

Some details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54793596/how-to-pass-multiple-string-variables-to-a-laravel-gate) and reading the `src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authorize.php` `getGateArguments()` method.

Note that you could also attach a Policy to your gate, and use the `request()` helper.

Comment: It worked! I didn't know such a convenient helper function was available. Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not super familiar with gates, but the `can` middleware is used with policies. It can pass arguments, but these are route parameters, as in [the canonical example](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#via-middleware):

```php
Route::put('/post/{post}', function (Post $post) {
    // The current user may update the post...
})->middleware('can:update,post');
```

`post` is defined as a route parameter, so when it's added to the `can` middleware, that model is passed as a parameter to the policy.

In cases where a model instance isn't needed, the name of the class is passed as a parameter to the policy, unless route model binding is used, in which case it will be a new instance of the given class. Again, this is used by policies not gates AFAIK, and will not give you the current request object.

---

The usual way to get the current request instance is to use [the `request()` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-request). Simply modify your code to look like this:

```php
Gate::define('foo', function (?User $user) {
    $request = request();
    /* some processes */
});
```

Comment: It worked! I didn't know such a convenient helper function was available. Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction.